What are the potential moral, ethical, and legal consequences of "committing" to a position for a two years, while planning to leave sooner?
I am a recent graduate and have been job searching for about a year now, and I am at this point in desperate need of employment. I spend on average 10 to 12 hours a day searching and preparing application materials, and as you can imagine I've submitted on the order of thousands of job applications.
I've only been offered interviews for two positions, and at my most recent interview I was told that I would only be permitted to move onto the next round if I could verbally commit to remaining in the position for two years. On the spot, I agreed. My true intentions, however, are to apply to graduate programs with hopes of starting to pursue a doctoral degree next Fall (a prerequisite for obtaining effectively any well-paying position in the field I studied in college).
What matters most right now is, of course, that I can pay the bills, and not that I am able to attend graduate school at some point in the future. If offered the job, I plan to take it no matter the stipulations involved. My question, however, is: what are the potential consequences of committing to two years in the event I receive a job offer, but leaving after just one?
I can imagine at the very least that there is significant potential to burn bridges (if I left to attend a graduate program, they would know that I had planned to do so whilst applying to the job).

Moral and ethical are matters of opinion, or possibly if philosophy. Legal is out of scope. If you want to ask impact on your career, that is more answerable.

Did they commit to not fire you in the first two years?

Ask them for a legal (binding) document, which may be a contract or an employee hand book ? That will tell you what may happen to you if you quit within 2 years.

Which country are you in ? Please add a country tag to get more accurate answers.

Are you sure a verbal commitment is all you have to give? I would expect the final paperwork (or however employment details are handled in your neck of the woods) to enshrine this, possibly with strings attached.

@Job_September_2020 My apologies. I thought I had added the united-states tag, no?

@MisterMiyagi I was asked for verbal confirmation before being allowed to proceed in the interview process. I suspect (but don’t know) that there will be some contract of some sort

@JoeStrazzere I’m told that my issue is the job market. Anecdotally, I have a number of friends, some much more experienced than myself that have been looking for as long or longer than I have. The career center at my uni. tells me that a number of recent grads have come to them complaining of difficulty finding work. I also have a couple of older family members that have been struggling to find work in spite of decades of experience. The job market is terrible at the moment. I’ve been turned down by multiple “last resort” minimum wage jobs in my area due to the huge # of applicants.

@JoeStrazzere Well, I verbally stated that I was willing to commit to two years. I was put on the spot, and this was not mentioned in either the job description nor any of my previous interviews. I have not yet formally agreed to anything in any serious way as I see it, nor agreed to a job offer. I am concerned about all three aspects, and I’m attempting to weigh my need for work and the possible consequences on both sides.

IMHO,
You had to agree to move forward.
Morally:
It is not moral or ethical to take advantage of less fortunate for personal gain, in reality - happens all the time
Legally:
If nothing signed - no obligation.
if signed, check the exit clause for penalties and consideration.
No consideration, penalty clause may be void and non enforceable due to duress.
For that, meeting with legal aid or employment lawyer may help understand the implications and enforceability
In short - wait and see if you get an offer and what would it be, until then, its all theoretical and you should go with the flow

Plus, while they may intend to apply to graduate school that does not mean that the will apply much less get in. But, carefully read the contract. Owing relocation or specialty training expenses is not uncommon, giving back salary would be illegal.

This looks a big red flag in my opinion. Asking for a long term commitment is silly, for several reasons. Imagine someone saying that they are willing to date you only if you commit to them for at least two years. Does this imply that, if you accept, they can abuse you in any way they want and you are not free to break the relationship?
Plus, they did not show any willingness to commit on their part; I'm pretty sure that they will fire you in a heartbeat if your work will be inconsistent.
So, burning bridges with someone who takes literally this kind of commitments is not a big deal. It's also possible that they are just pressuring you, hoping they won't need to replace you soon and won't have hard feelings when you will leave, since they know that what they are asking is unreasonable.

I don't think it's necessarily silly or a red flag. But such a commitment is a fairly big ask, and so should be compensated, for example by a similar commitment from their side, or an increased salary. If there's no such consideration, then I agree: red flag.

It is somewhat different in academia vs. industry, but worth noting this type of long-term upfront commitment is basically what the OP will face if pursuing a doctorate - no department wants a PhD student who doesn't have a clear intention to stick around for years on end. Depending on the exact phrasing of the question, I might interpret it as more about intent than a (frankly unbelievable) promise that the OP would stick around "no matter what". Agree the interviewer would be foolish to take the 2-year commitment too literally.

If they want you for at least 2 years than they are welcome to add a time commitment to your work contract. The OP can then make a value judgment i.r.t whether the offer is worth it for him.

The question is: Does the company have a good justification to ask for a two year commitment?
If they ask for a two year commitment to a shelf stacking job, that's nonsense. You check carefully that you don't sign anything legally binding and then you do whatever is best for you.
If you are offered a job that requires one year of very company specific training when you produce nothing of value at full pay, then it is totally justified that they will want a two year commitment. And there will be a contract that ensures that. In that situation it is unethical to take the job when you know today that you will never produce useful work for them, and probably will cause you legal problems.
There are jobs where you would be expected to be productive in the first year, but much less than in the second year. In that situation the decision is up to you, but you might want to try to get a different job first.

At will employment cuts both way.
If an employer can fire you for basically any reason, you can quit for any reason.
Unless, you commit to a two-year work contract formally and in writing saying you will stay on for two years verbally does not mean much.
I would not advise any employee in the west to give an ounce of consideration to what is ethical or right in the workplace. As long as you are not breaking any laws you are not doing anything wrong.

Ethics are important. Regarding an employer's wants or needs as more important than one's own wants or needs is not ethical (and also not not ethical).

I have no compentence to comment on the legality.  But the moral side of it seems really obvious:  You would be deliberately lying--that's wrong.
You were caught by surprise, and I understand the snap decision to agree under pressure.  But it would not be right to continue on and deliberately commit to a term of employment which you have no intention of carrying-out.
If I ever come across that question in an interview I plan on responding, "I'd consider it as long as the committment goes both ways.  How many years would you guarantee my employment at this job with at least this salary?"

Can they legally bind you to your job for two years? In some states they might be able to do so. I don't know much about US law. So double check anything you sign, to make sure this is not the case.
I would accept. As for the morals of leaving early. I wouldn't feel that bad, but that is obviously up to your moral standards and nobody will be able to answer this question for you.
Given your situation I would accept any job I can get that I feel comfortable with doing and go from there. You've obviously have problems finding a job so take this opportunity unless there is something else wrong with it.
Two years is not a long time and who knows how you feel in another year. You might want to stay the extra year or not. You might apply for the graduate program and not be accepted. You might be accepted for the program but push the beginning to a year later. You might be able to cut a deal with the company if they're happy with you and want to keep you to finish your graduation and return working for them. I would internally assume for now to do the job for at least two years. And next year you can see. The point is focus on now.
As for burning bridges. Yes if you ever apply to the same company they might not take you if you quit early.

In the US you cannot be forced to work for a company. You can sign an agreement that training costs and signing bonuses will be returned if you leave before a specific date but you will always have the ability to leave. Slavery is illegal in the US. However, depending on how large the field is, leaving before that date could have serious ramifications. You could effectively block yourself from being hired in the future by earning yourself a bad reputation

@Donald So fixed term employment contracts don't exist at all in the US? When I had one (in the EU), it didn't really feel like slavery, more like great job security. As an employee, you know you will have a job for a year, no matter what happens. Company changes their mind, wants to cut costs and lay people off? Too bad, there's no way to get rid of you until the contract runs out.

@Donald Signing a contract where you commit to a certain amount/time of work and risk damages and other legal consequences if you don't isn't exactly slavery though.

@marcelm - I didn’t say it was, but that contract, has an escape clause if it doesn’t then that’s close to slavery.

@TooTea - They are extremely rare, and when they do exist, they are rarely paid entirely up front.

There are ways to exit fixed terms contracts obviously too in Europe. But usually it has severe repercussions. That is the point. The one exception is probably the military you can get court martialed for leaving them.

You will burn a bridge. It is unlikely that you will be able to work for this company again in the future.
It depends
A verbal agreement to not leave until working for them is worth the paper it was written on. Much like a verbal agreement to hire you, or not fire you for 2 years.
Your employment contract, the thing you sign that says how much they will pay you and lists your job responsibilities will tell you what the penalties are for leaving early, if any. Everything else is just words on the wind. As a side note, they are only legally allowed to require you to return a signing bonus, and/or training costs.
They are not allowed to require you to return your salary or hourly pay.
Until you have the employment offer in your hand, we cannot answer this question. And any answer to this question will be specific to your case. And reading your employment offer will tell it to you anyways (consult with a labor lawyer if you cannot understand it).
my recommendation Go for it, at least until you have an offer on the table and than can see what the penalties/cost really is. Who knows you might change your mind about getting a masters after making real money, a lot of people do. You also might find a way to have them pay for your masters/higher education, which will require a further contract to work even more years for the company. The usual penalty for that is that you have to pay the cost of your masters/PhD, with a cost reduction based on how long you worked for them after getting masters/PhD.

Nothing.
Other side, your employer would likely just don't believe your "commitment", not even if it would be real. As a newbie, he can also probably see a high chance that he will fire you earlier.
If you had a work history, your employer would check that, he would imagine your life path and he would interpret that with your interview behavior together. That would be convincing for him.
The fallback is, that as a beginner, your salary and other important job parameters are probably limited (compared to a more experienced workforce with a clear employment history).
The moral side is that anything can happen which changes your life. For example, a stellar once-in-a-life offer.
